# How can I enable dynamic paint in the viewport without the weight colors?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, dynamic-paint

I like to use dynamic paint to manipulate vertex groups between modifiers in the modifier stack (e.g. after an Array modifier to control a particle system).

By default it visualizes the weight colors on the object.  This is good for adjusting the DP settings, but otherwise impedes the visibility of the model's topology, and is generally ugly.  However when I uncheck the *Display modifier in viewport* button it not only goes back to normal shading on the object but also disables the actual DP results (in the viewport).  So all following modifiers use the vertex group as per pre-DP.

[image]

Is there a way of *just* turning off the weight color visibility of the DP modifier without disabling it's effects entirely in the viewport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the *Dynamic Paint* rollout of the *Physics* panel (on the canvas object) there is a *Display surface preview in 3D views* eye-button next to each DP surface slot.  This does exactly what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: It took the millionth-and-first time of searching that menu to find it!